# What does --> mean in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, syntax

```
for (int i = 99; i --> 0;) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Above code works, and has the exactly same result of

```
for (int i = 99; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

What does the syntax "-->" originally mean in Java? Since almost reachable search engines disallow special characters, I cannot seem to find the answer.

Comment: @onegrx Well, the original one has 3k.

Comment: Great senior developers write their code so that it can be read by others....only a junior would want to use this, to make him look like a pro...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## `-->` is not a new operator.

It is just a *conjunction* of the operators `--` and  `>`.

You first compare, and then decrement the variable.

That is,

```
i --> 0
```

becomes *effectively*

```
i > 0; //Compare
i--; //and decrement
```

Comment: It's the reverse actually. First comparison, then decrement.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but whoever did, that's probably because you're answer is still not fully current. Your 3rd statement still needs change.

Answer (score 10):

`i --> 0` means `i>0 and i--` :: i is decremented first (returns non-decremented value) and then compared to `0`.

This is a conjunction.

Answer (score 5):

`-->` is not any operator. It is just the cocatenation of `--` and `>`.

So when you write

`i-->0` it means compare the value of `i` and then decrement it.

So for better readability it can be written as

```
for (int i = 99; (i--)> 0;) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Notice here the increment/decrement place does not appear. So it decrements `i` by 1 but returns same non-decremented value and then compares `i` with `0`.

The comparison checks whether `i` is greater than `0` after the decrement is performed(but not returned).

Answer (score 2):

`i-- > 0`

`i--`  is post decrement

`>`  is greater than

```
for (initialization; boolean expression; updation){
 `//some code`
}
```

So you did initialization and but you checked boolean expression and updated in one step so it worked.

Answer (score 1):

There is no operator as `-->` it's simply `i--` and  `i>0`;
first, it will do post decrement.
then it will check the condition and compare it with `0` whether it's greater than or not.

Remember it's value will not be changed while comparison (i will be 1) after comparison it will decrement the value (i will now be 0) and printed.

Comment: First it will do the comparison, then the post-decrement. That's what 'post' means.